# Convert date String to dateformatter in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdateformatter

I fetch data from an API. In this API, there is an date element that comes in `String` 
Here is the format of getting this date info:

```
 cell.nameLabel.text = timelineData[indexPath.row].updatedAt
```

and here is the string date format: `"2013-01-03T17:24:28Z"`

I want to sort this array base of the this date, but I think I should first convert it to the date format from String, is it right?

If yes, could you help me to how to do that? Can I do it in the same array or I have to create a new array for that? I will be appreciated if you can help me on that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISO8601 date string format is sortable. You can sort the array descending in place

```
timelineData.sort{$0.updatedAt > $1.updatedAt}
```

The newest item comes first. If you want the oldest item first replace `>` with `<`

Comment: thank you so much, but does it work with String? The API provide this information as String, not the Valid date formatter

Comment: Please reload the page and reread the first sentence in my answer 

Comment: Thanks, I asked it because I got this error: 'Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'UIContentSizeCategory''

Comment: `updatedAt` is obviously an optional. You are encouraged to declare it as non-optional if the property has always a value. I do not understand the part `UIContentSizeCategory`. The text label seems to be `String`.

Comment: It wants to to change it to : timelineData.sort{UIContentSizeCategory(rawValue: $0.updatedAt!) > UIContentSizeCategory(rawValue: $1.updatedAt!)} . But still doesn't work

Comment: Why? The code makes no sense.  `updatedAt` is `String` and is not related at all to `UIContentSizeCategory`

Comment: It works when I tried to force unwrap it. Thank you so much for helping me on that.